# Get the coordinate of that point every 100 meters along a route

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes, maps, coordinates

I have a start point and a destination point. I want to take the coordinates of that point on the map every 100 meters on this route. How can I do it ? Is there anyone who can help?

I've been searching for google maps api but couldn't find it

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I considered the first 3 as dupicates, but they use `GetPointAtDistance` (singular) instead `GetPointsAtDistance` (plural), but the last one I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Williams wrote an extension for the Google Maps JavaScript API v2 called [`epoly`](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm), which contains the method `GetPointsAtDistance`, which sounds like what you are looking for.

> .GetPointsAtDistance(metres)
> Returns an array of GLatLngs of points at the specified interval along the path.
> By calculating all the points in a single pass, this runs a lot faster than calling GetPointAtDistance() in a loop. If the path is shorter than the specified distance, then it returns null.

There is a version ported to v3 here: http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xbycs3un/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
let polyline;
let markers = [];

function initMap() {
  initEpoly();
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    },
  });
  polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeWeight: 3,
    map: map
  });
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);

  const onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
  };

  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  polyline.setPath([]);
  clearMarkers();
  directionsService
    .route({
      origin: {
        query: document.getElementById("start").value,
      },
      destination: {
        query: document.getElementById("end").value,
      },
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      renderDirections(response, map);
      var points = polyline.GetPointsAtDistance(100);
      console.log(points.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: points[i],
          title: "" + i,
          icon: {
            url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
          }
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status));
}

function renderDirections(response, map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
        bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  markers = [];
}

window.initMap = initMap;

function initEpoly() {
  /*********************************************************************\
   *                                                                     *
   * epolys.js                                          by Mike Williams *
   * updated to API v3                                  by Larry Ross    *
   *                                                                     *
   * A Google Maps API Extension                                         *
   *                                                                     *
   * Adds various Methods to google.maps.Polygon and google.maps.Polyline *
   */
  // === A method which returns an array of GLatLngs of points a given interval along the path ===
  google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance = function(metres) {
    var next = metres;
    var points = [];
    // some awkward special cases
    if (metres <= 0) return points;
    var dist = 0;
    var olddist = 0;
    for (var i = 1;
      (i < this.getPath().getLength()); i++) {
      olddist = dist;
      dist += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.getPath().getAt(i), this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
      while (dist > next) {
        var p1 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 1);
        var p2 = this.getPath().getAt(i);
        var m = (next - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat() + (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * m));
        next += metres;
      }
    }
    return points;
  }
}
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", "sans-serif";
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Directions Service</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Start: </b>
    <input id="start" value="New York, NY" />
    <b>End: </b>
    <input id="end" value="Soho, NY" />
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="get directions" />
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- 
     The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
     document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
     and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
     with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```